Open app from Instagram webview on Android
When the user is browsing a web page in the Instagram webview, there doesn't appear to be a way to open another app that the user has installed on their Android device.
I have Android App Links set up to open a certain URL in my app, and this works fine on Chrome. However, these links don't work that well on Android webviews (including Instagram).
The workaround that I found for Android webviews was Android Intent links, where you essentially wrap the link inside intent:<URL>#Intent;end, and worked well on all webviews, until last week when they started failing on Instagram. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there any other way to escape the Instagram webview on Android?

"this works fine on Chrome" -- note that they may not work by default on other browsers, such as Firefox and Samsung Internet. There is no requirement for an app to allow hyperlinks to open another app. In the case of Firefox and Samsung Internet, the last I checked, they had that feature disabled by default for security reasons.

@CommonsWare, "it works on Chrome" was mainly to highlight that the Android App Links had been setup correctly. Also, in my tests it appeared that the Android Intent links did open the app in all the other browsers I tested (including Firefox and Samsung Intent).

Understood. That does not mean that Instagram is obligated to support deeplinks like these.

The links appear to be working again, so I guess it was just a bug that they fixed now.
